# C++ static library is not compiling in xcode on mac

Tags: c++, static-libraries, xcode9.3

I am new to stack overflow. I am developing a static c++ library on mac using xcode(9.3). It was compiling and running fine but then i did some code changes and after that its showing some strange compile time errors. like 
"/clang:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)". Any help will be much appreciated.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "LJCPPBL_CORE::LJCPPBL::Initialize(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "LJCPPBL_CORE::LJCPPBL::GetShortestPath(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, float*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "LJCPPBL_CORE::LJCPPBL::GetJson()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Above text is showing in log.

This is the LJCPPBL header file "LJCPPBL.hpp"

```
#ifndef LJCPPBL_hpp
#define LJCPPBL_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include "../Models/Models.hpp"
#include <list>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace LJCPPBL_Models;

namespace LJCPPBL_CORE {

 class LJCPPBL
    {
        public: static void Initialize(string clientAPIKEY);
        public: static string GetJson();
        public: static void SetJson(string strJson);
        public: static list<Destination> GetDestinationsList();
        public: static list<Point> GetShortestPath(string source, string destination, float* costOfPath);
    };
}

#endif /* LJCPPBL_hpp */
```

This is the Implementation of LJCPPBL header file "LJCPPBL.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LJCPPBL.hpp"
#include "../Models/Models.hpp"
#include "../DAL/DataAccess.cpp"
#include "../Plugins/JsonParser/json.hpp"
#include "SPC.cpp"
#include "GlobalValues.cpp"
#include <list>

using namespace std;
using namespace LJCPPBL_CORE;
using namespace LJCPPBL_DAL;

namespace  LJCPPBL_CORE{
void LJCPPBL::Initialize(string clientAPIKEY){
        auto globalValues = new GlobalValues();
        LJCPPBLGlobalValues = *globalValues;
        LJCPPBLGlobalValues.ClientAPIKey = clientAPIKEY;
    }

    string LJCPPBL::GetJson()
    {
        LJCPPBLAPIDAL* objDAL = new LJCPPBLAPIDAL();
        string mapPointsAndPathJson = objDAL -> GetMapsAndPointsJSON();
        string mapDestinationJSON = objDAL -> GetMapDestinationsJSON();
        json jsonObj = {{"MapPointsAndPathJSON", mapPointsAndPathJson}, {"MapDestinationJSON", mapDestinationJSON} };
        return jsonObj.dump();
    }

    void LJCPPBL::SetJson(string strJson)
    {

    }

    list<Destination> LJCPPBL::GetDestinationsList()
    {
         LJCPPBLAPIDAL* objDAL = new LJCPPBLAPIDAL();
        return objDAL -> GetDestinations();
    }

    list<Point> LJCPPBL::GetShortestPath(string source, string destination, float* costOfPath)
    {
        return SPC::GetShortestPath(source, destination, costOfPath);
    }
}
//#endif
```

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: hey @IceFire, publish your comment as an answer.

Comment: @AdolfoAbegg ok

Comment: 1. Please learn how to get copyable text error messages from your IDE.  Screenshots are never a good way to convey this information.

Comment: 2.  You need to include a [mcve] *in the question itself*.  A link to a third party website is not acceptable.

Comment: 3.  What was the change?

Comment: @MartinBonner I have seen a ton's of questions and answers on stack-overflow which have links to github,microsoft forum which are third party sites.

Comment: Those questions will get downvoted, and closed. See "How to ask" in the help centre.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the linker error and select "show in log", this will give you real details about the error.

Most likely, it's some unresolved external symbol, so you might not have linked some library or some cpp file to your project.

After edit of question:
There seems to be some library "LJCPPBL" that you have not linked in. At least, you have not linked the core module. You need to set library paths and add library files to your project.

Comment: I have pasted the log text in my question. Could you please have a look and help me on this.

Comment: @BijayDixit I have added a bit to the answer

Comment: LJCPPBL is not a library. its a class defined by me. I have included the code of the class in my code

Comment: @BijayDixit then, have you added the cpp file to your project?

Comment: yes i have added the cpp file to my project